# vertex groups created from rigging do not work

Tags: armature, rigging, vertex-groups, weight-painting

I successfully rigged a high poly 3 piece model and upon skinning the model, the vertex groups were created for all parts of the model. However, the "Neck, Head" and "Hair" vertex groups while created are not recognized in "Weight Paint" and upon applying "Weight Paint" manually there is no effect?
The "Red" paint appears but does not allow heat, animation of the head or neck. The rest of the model works fine with "Weight Paint" and moves correctly. While I am new to blender what would be the best approached to this situation?

**[The model](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29198)**

Comment: A Latest Model Revised Copy, Use This   http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29250

Comment: For me there are two problems: The first download has no rig at all. The second download doesn't move as described. But maybe the problem is that the head isn't merged with the rest of the model.

Comment: One problem is, that there is no armature modifier for head and hair. The mesh is also a bit of a mess (probably due to import/export) so using automatic weights might fail. I'd split all lose parts and separate them into different objects, call automatic weights and fix the weighting by hand afterwards, then join everything back together as needed.

Comment: Okay! "WorldSEnder" the idea to "Merge" was a great idea! while "user2859"s idea of the "Armature Modifier" was a wonderful idea which was the resolve of the inanimate items! I selected the "Head, Hair" and "Eyes" then selected the armature, rig while in object mode and applied "CRTL P" with "Automatic Weights" I then provided additional weight an all works good but still needs works but at least it functions as a 1 piece model..thanks much guys!

Comment: @WorldSEnder Care to add an answer since it seems it have solved the the OPs issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a rig make sure that every part of the model has an Armature Modifier applied. This is easy when you Merge (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> in Object Mode) all of the objects you want to rig into one "big" object which means that you only have to apply the Armature Modifier once.

Another "feature" of Blender that comes to mind when thinking about rigging with custom weights is that the weigths are assigned with a vertex group. The vertex group's name has to be the same as the Bone's you want to bind the group to. You can always try to get away with automated weights or use them as a base for your own weightpaint, it gives a decent result most of the time.

Comment: Great Work!....marvelous! very much appreciated!